# ucwords doesn't work when After Slash (/) Symbol

Tags: php, string

I write this code

```
echo ucwords('online/offline');
```

expected result : `Online/Offline`

result: `Online/offline`

How to make first letter after slash symbol become capital letter without adding spaces?

Comment: try these  `echo ucwords('online / offline');`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add `delimiters` on the second paremeter of `ucwords`

```
echo ucwords('online/offline', '/');
```

This will result to:

```
Online/Offline
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

> The optional delimiters contains the word separator characters.

Answer (score 3):

ucwords supports delimiter parameter:

```
echo ucwords('online/offline', '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

because ucwords()  Convert the first character of each word to uppercase and each word differ by space
if you used this one 
`echo ucwords('online/offline', '/');`

than not work for

'echo ucwords ('online offline','/')`

you should pass all character that separate the word for e.g

`echo ucwords('online/offline', '/, ');`